# How can I factor the behaviour of static methods in a superclass?

Tags: java, inheritance, java-8, null-check

I need to create a series of transformer classes that transform an object into an other one.

They are of the form

```
class Transformer1 {
    public static AnotherClass transform(MyClass source) {
        return AnotherClass.newBuilder()
                .setName(source.getName())
                // etc
                .build();
    }
}
```

I have about 15 of them.

These transformers for now assume that the parameter is not null. Otherwise I would get an NullPointerException.

I would like to add a null check, ie:

```
class Transformer1 {
    public static AnotherClass transform(MyClass source) {
        if(source == null)
            return null;
        return AnotherClass.newBuilder()
                .setName(source.getName())
                // etc
                .build();
    }
}
```

but I don't want to write this null check on every transformer class. I was thinking of factoring it in a super class or interface.

```
abstract class BaseTransformer {

    public static AnotherClass transform(MyClass source) {
        return source == null ? null : transformNonNull(source);
    }

    public abstract AnotherClass transformNonNull(MyClass source);
}
```

and all my subclasses could implement the `transformNonNull` method.

Now that doesn't work because we are dealing with static methods and `transformNonNull` would need to be static. But it can't be static and abstract.

I could make my transformers non static, but really they have no state and are more like utilities, so I would like to keep them static.

I already encountered this issue in the past and didn't really come up with a solution. Waht would be the best approach here?

**EDIT:**

Object A has fields a1, a2, ... Ax
and I want to transform it into an object B with fields b1, b2, ... bx

My transformers are transformers for these fields into one another.
In my case, `a2` could be null, and that would be perfectly acceptable. I don't want to through an exception if `a2` is null and I can't build `b2` from it. In this case I want to set `b2` to null also

Comment: Throwing an exception when the argument is `null`, is a reasonable behavior. Returning `null` instead, only means making it someone else’s problem, at a point where it might be hard to impossible, to find out where the values started to be `null`. So “the best approach” is not to make this questionable change at all.

Comment: @Holger I understand that in terms of the transformer, it would be better to assume it is never null, but I need to do that check somewhere because null is acceptable in my case and should be "transformed" to null. See my edit. So I am just moving the check to the call, saying, if not null then transform, otherwise set null

Comment: Why are these transformer methods static? Why not have an `interface Transformer<From, To>{ To transform(From input)}`. Then you can have them inherit super-class methods or have a static helper method to do your null-check before dispatching to a transformer. How do you call your 15 unrelated static methods now? A huge chain of if/else ?

Comment: "I could make my transformers non static, but really they have no state and are more like utilities, so I would like to keep them static." State is not the only reason to use objects. Another is dynamic dispatch, code-reuse through inheritance, de-coupling of interface and implementation.

Comment: ok guys, I think I will make them non static, and have a super class, it will make things lot easier. I am using Spring so making them singletons is easy. Thanks all for the input.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AspectJ to insert the null check into the relevant methods.